# Angular HTTPClients: combine HTTP-requests and Observables for async

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have bascially in my HTML code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="lstSearchResults|async as resultList; else searching">
...
 <cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport class="scroll-container">
      <div *cdkVirtualFor="let search of resultList"  class="card-item" >
```

and in the `ts` code:

```
 this.lstSearchResults = this.http.post<SearchResult[]>('services/search', search);
```

which means that the `lstSearchResults` is displayed in the list. As long as the content is always replaced with a new list the code is working quite fine, i.e. I can fill 20 items at once and than the next 20 items, etc....

I want to use the new Angular7 feature of a [VirtualScrollPane](https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling). I have the requirement that a new search should add 20 new items to the existing list, i.e. the new list should have new length of 40 items.

My approach with something like this

```
this.lstSearchResults.pipe(mergeMapTo (this.http.post<SearchResult[]>('services/search', search));
this.http.post<SearchResult[]>('services/search', search).pipe(mergeMapTo(this.lstSearchResults));
```

fails since [the comment](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-delete-request) clearly states a `subscribe()` is required to execute the `Post` request. So is there a way to combine the results to

1. Have a new list of 40 items
2. Loading of items is done `async`, i.e. I do not have to worry when the request is finished.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html).

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';

let req1 = this.http.post<SearchResult[]>('services/search', search);
let req2 = http.post<SearchResult[]>('services/search', search);

return forkJoin([req1 , req2]).pipe(map(result => [...result[0], ...result[1]]));
```

Comment: If I follow your advice than I would have `this.lstSearchResults=forkJoin(this.lstSearchResults, this.searchService.doSearch(searchConfig)).pipe(map(result => [...result[0], ...result[1]]));` which unfortunatly only doubles the content. I don't get the first 20 items and then the next e.g. 11 items, i.e. have in total 31 items. I have with your approach just 22 items (i.e. 11 doubled).

Comment: I have just shown you, how to combine the asynchronous results. I don't know how your responses look like. May be if you add that, I can suggest you to contact.